# Can CMake (or similar) generate Visual C++ projects which don't use cl.exe?

Tags: visual-c++, cmake

Is it possible to use CMake (or another build automation utility) to generate Visual C++ projects, which use a C++ compiler *other than* cl.exe? Ideally it could locate the relevant compatible C++ standard library; and allow step debugging; but one step at a time: if it could even compile an empty `main` function, that would be a good start.

Comment: I feel there's some confusion underlying this question... First of all, ninja doesn't generate VS projects - ninja makefiles are a *target* for cmake, to allow building using the ninja tool. But most importantly, you don't need a VC++ project to perform source level debugging with Visual Studio, as long as the compiler emits the debug information in a compatible format (namely, PDB) the VC++ debugger works perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks Matteo, I've updated the question. If you are aware of a solution, please feel free to contribute an answer.

Comment: Both the Intel compiler and Clang can be made available as a Platform Toolset in Visual Studio. For example, by cmake -G"Visual Studio 12 Win64" -T"Intel C++ Compiler XE 14.0" <sources>, I generate visual studio project and solution files, but compile with the intel compiler

Comment: Debugging is unrelated to CMake. That must be supported by your compiler and your IDE. Usually you can debug with Visual Studio and every common compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CMake distinguishes Generators and Toolsets.

Generators produce control files for build systems, for example `Makefile`s for make or `.sol` files for Visual Studio or `.ninja` files for Ninja-build. There are several generators for various platforms. The generator is passed to `cmake` with `-G`. As you want to use Visual C++, you have to use `Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64` or `Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64`. [[documentation]](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake-generators.7.html)

Toolsets specify the used compiler. This can be a cross-compiler or simply an alternative compiler (MinGW or Clang instead of cl.exe). The toolset must bu supported by the generator. You the the toolset via `-T`. Currently the toolsets are poorly documented and there is no list of available toolsets. To use the Intel compiler, use something similar to `Intel C++ Compiler XE 14.0`.

Overall this gives you

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -T "Intel C++ Compiler XE 14.0" ..
```

to generate a project from the parent directory with VS 2015 and Intel C++ 14 compiler.

Comment: Note: for the 2016 version of the Intel compiler the syntax has changed slightly; leave out ``XE``; I had to use ``-T"Intel C++ Compiler 16.0"``